# Why does IOS give this error and Android doesnt (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, google-maps

Im making an app using react native. It uses the google maps api and I wrote a good amount of code which displays a map, adds markers and highlights a route between markers. I wrote code so that when a user presses the screen they add a marker and the markers coords get added into a list. When they click the marker that was placed on the screen it gets removed. The problem is this only works on android. When I try on IOS i get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8mZi.png)

I tried many different variations of these 2 methods. the two methods are onMarkerPress and the other onPress()

```
const [markers, setMarker] = useState([]);

// this method is used to delete the marker
const onMarkerPress = (index) => {
    setMarker((prevMarkers) => {
    console.log("Marker Pressed!", index);
    const updatedMarkers = [...markers];
    updatedMarkers.splice(index, 1);
    setMarker(updatedMarkers);
      return updatedMarkers;
    });
  };

<MapView
          ref={mapRef}
          style={styles.map}
        
          //Region={mapRegion}
          initialRegion ={{
            latitude: 50,
            longitude: -70,
            latitudeDelta: 0.25,
            longitudeDelta: 0.25,
          }}
          zoomControlEnabled={true}
          zoomEnabled={true}
    
          onPress={(e) => {
            setMarker((prevMarkers) => {
              const newMarkers = [...prevMarkers, e.nativeEvent.coordinate];
              console.log(newMarkers);
              return newMarkers;
            });
          }}
>  

// this markers method loops through the marker array and displays them on the map
 {markers.map((marker, index) => (
          marker && (<Marker
            key={index} 
            coordinate={marker}
            // this calls the above method to delete the markers when user clicks them
            onPress={event => onMarkerPress(index)}
            
            

          />
         
 </MapView>
```

Comment: That is not an error, that is a warning.

Comment: updated the image to show the error instead of the warning

Answer (score 0):

Don‘t pass a callback to the state setter here:

Change:

```
  onPress={(e) => {
            setMarker((prevMarkers) => {
              const newMarkers = [...prevMarkers, e.nativeEvent.coordinate];
              console.log(newMarkers);
              return newMarkers;
            });
          }}
```

To:

```
    onPress={(e) => {
     setMarker([...markers  , e.nativeEvent.coordinate]);
    }}>
```

To replace the marker:

```
onPress={(e) => {
 setMarker([e.nativeEvent.coordinate]);
}}
```

This will `[...markers  , e.nativeEvent.coordinate]` create a new array with all items in marker and `e.nativeEvent.coordinate`

Comment: Cheers! that gets rid of the errors on IOS so the app isnt crashing but the markers arent being removed when clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my answer.